# How set my modified by field whenever my repository updates are called?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring jpa data. I would like to manage a modifiedBy field to an entity. I'm using an interceptor and it works when I extract an entity, change something and save the entity back in the repository. But when I use a direct update query the interceptor isn't called.

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.password = ?2 WHERE u.id = ?1 ")
public void updatePassword(Long userId, String encodePassword);
```

Also tried to use an `AuditEntityListener` like in [this](http://hantsy.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/jpa-data-auditing.html) post, but again the same problem. How do I create an infrastructure that will set my `modifiedBy` whenever my repository updates are called?

Answer (score 0):

An `EntityListener` based approach won't work because the API is based on entity instances being loaded into the persistence context. This seems to be what you want to avoid explicitly. The only option is to manually set the date in your query definition explicitly:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.password = ?2, u.modifiedBy = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
       " WHERE u.id = ?1 ")
void updatePassword(Long userId, String encodePassword);
```

Comment: That's what I did. I hoped there is a better way.